# How can I increase the size of the accordion height

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm a beginner.I have used jQuery slideshow inside accordion. The slideshow and accordion works fine. But, my problem is to increase the height of the display space in the accordion as I have to keep the pictures visible.
Is there anyway I can do this I tried -

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
autoHeight: false, active: false, collapsible: true,heightStyle: "fill" 
    });
  });
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
      minHeight: 140,
      minWidth: 300,
      resize: function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
      }
    });
  });  </script>
```

But, I could not increase the height of the accordion space as I have to show atleast one row of images.
Below is the screenshot - 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "heightStyle", "content");
```

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/